# Indexing with Boolean arrays

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-ndarray, numpy-slicing

```
a = np.arange(12).reshape(3,4)

b1 = np.array([False,True,True]

b2 = np.array([True,False,True,False])

a[b1,b2]
```

output:

```
array([4,10])
```

I am not getting how it comes 4 and 10 in a[b1,b2]

Comment: I'd be interested if anybody has an answer.

Comment: Can you explain what you expected to get and why?

Comment: I'm having trouble understanding why `a[:,[True,True,True,True]]`  and `a[[True,True,True],:]` return the entire array `a` but `a[[True,True,True],[True,True,True,True]]` triggers a broadcasting error. There is something here that I don't understand. Numpy is not simply computing the outer product of the two index lists and returning the elements that evaluate to `True`. The [documentation](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html#boolean-array-indexing) doesn't seem to help much either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apparently you expected to see `array([[ 4,  6],[ 8, 10]])`.

In boolean indexing NumPy returns only diagonal elements as described [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/reference/arrays.indexing.html):

> without the `np.ix_` call, only the diagonal elements would be selected(...). This difference is the most important thing to remember about indexing with multiple advanced indexes.

For the desired output use `np.ix_()`:

```
a[np.ix_(b1,b2)]
```

Comment: Do you mean the diagonal of  `array([ [4,6], [8,10] ])`?

Comment: to @NachiketGokhale: Yes, after such logical indexing numpy will return diagonal of that array.

Comment: What if the returned array is not square?

Comment: to @NachiketGokhale: the original `a[b1,b2]` expression is defined only if b1 and b2 have equal number of `True` values. Otherwise it will throw `IndexError: shape mismatch` exception. Thus only diagonal array is a possible alternative here if you use `a[np.ix_(b1,b2)]` expression.
Note, that unlike`a[b1,b2]`, the `a[np.ix_(b1,b2)]` works with any number of true values.

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(12).reshape(3, 4)
b1 = np.array([False,True,True])
b2 = np.array([True,False,True,False])
print(a)
print(a[b1, b2])
```

The first thing is that you have arranged 12 array elements which are starting with 0, step with 1, and stop with 12.
And then you have reshaped your array elements with 3 rows and 4 columns.
look like the following:

```
[[ 0  1  2  3]
 [ 4  5  6  7]
 [ 8  9 10 11]]
```

Then finally printing the array elements with row and column because the array is a two-dimensional array it has rows and columns.\
b1 is representing the rows of the elements which have three rows and the first row(row[0]) is False.
The second row (row[1]) is True.... the last row(row[2]) is True.
b2 also representing the columns of the array which has 4 columns. The first column(column[0]) is True...The third column(column[2]) is True.
and The last is False.
Then when we want to return the output of the two-dimensional array we use array name(a[b1, b2]), b1 and b2 are row index and column indexes.

The second row and the first column becomes True. therefore it returns 4. The others are False. And also the third row and column also become True. Therefore, it returns 10. The others are False.

This is what I understood.
Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score -2):

The correct explanation is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/issues/16885). To summarize,

`a[b1,b2]` with boolean arrays `b1` and `b2` is equivalent to `a[b1.nonzero(),b2.nonzero()]`.

`nonzero()` returns indices of True values. Therefore,

```
b1.nonzero()=(array([1, 2]),)
b2.nonzero()=(array([0, 2]),)
```

So, now, we're indexing with arrays. As with array based indexing, the `[1,0]th` element which is `4` and the `[2,2]th` element which is `10` is returned.